# UIImageView is disappearing behind cell row in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UIImageView that is supposed to cover the selected row from a UITableView.  Both, the UIImageView, and UITableView are added to the main View inside Interface Builder.  Instead of covering up the cell when it is selected, the UIImageView moves to the selected cell and disappears behind it.  What I need it to do is move up to the selected row, and cover it up (i.e. the image should be in front of the cell, not behind it).  Please also bear in mind that my image needs to only cover the selected row.  Here is my relevant code:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        //CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] fromView:tableView];
        _imageView.frame = rect;
    }];

}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, and know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Is your imageView added before or after your table view to the subviews? Try to use bringSubviewToFront method.

Comment: Thanks very much, your solution worked!  Can you post our answer as a solution so that I may I award you the correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply because the imageView is added before the table view in the subviews, I guess. Hence you can use *bringSubviewToFront* method and apply it to the imageView after you add your tableView to the subviews, for example.